# short story where earthling artist travels to another planet where everyone is talented

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi

I am looking for the title of a story published in the 1980's the plot explores the value of art when the artist struggles (earthling) versus artist who has no problems producing any artwork (natives of the other planet).

Comment: Can you recall any other details? Right now there may not be much to go on.

Comment: Would this be a story where he discovers that his "talent" on the planet is to be the audience.

Comment: Hi Joseph, is "A Man of Talent" the story you were looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You may be thinking of Robert Silverberg's story [*A Man of Talent*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?64952), later reworked as *A Man with Talent*. It was first published in 1956, and collected in "[The Songs of Summer and Other Stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?47535)" in 1979. Here's a summary from [Majipoor.com](http://www.majipoor.com/work.php?id=717):

> Emil Vilar is the last truly talented poet on Earth, but he lives in a society where real poetry, the kind written by the likes of Yeats or Pound, is not valued. So he decides to go somewhere else—the colony world of Rigel Seven, settled centuries ago by sixteen families. Surely they would appreciate a true poet. But when he gets there, he finds that everyone is a poet. And a musician. And a painter. The arts are cultivated in all people, and a mere poet seems pitifully under-cultured.

Comment: FWIW, the "point" of the story was that he found a new purpose. Being the outsider, and trained in the arts, he was valuable as a critic to them.

Comment: You can read it at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Future_Science_Fiction_31_1956-1957-Winter).